# Using Maybe [String] at Haskell

Tags: haskell

i want to return a string using Maybe [String], but i can't manage to do it using Maybe.

Should i define an instance?

```
data Contacto = Casa Integer
              | Trab Integer
              | Tlm Integer
              | Email String
              deriving (Show)
type Nome = String
type Agenda = [(Nome, [Contacto])]

addEmail :: Nome -> String -> Agenda -> Agenda
addEmail n email agenda = (n, [Email email]):(agenda)


verEmails :: Nome -> Agenda -> [String]
verEmails n [] = []
verEmails n ((nome, ((Email e):ls)):xs) = if n == nome then (e:(verEmails n xs))
                                                       else (verEmails n xs)
```

Here is the same function verEmails, where i use Maybe:

```
verEmails :: Nome -> Agenda -> Maybe [String]
verEmails n [] = Nothing
verEmails n ((nome, ((Email e):ls)):xs) = if n == nome then Just (e:(verEmails n xs))
                                                       else (verEmails n xs)
```

The error that GHCi gives me:

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type `[String]'
>                 with actual type `Maybe [String]'
>     In the return type of a call of `verEmails'
>     In the second argument of `(:)', namely `(verEmails n xs)'
>     In the first argument of `Just', namely `(e : (verEmails n xs))'
> ```

Comment: What isn't working about it?  Is there a compiler error?  If so, post that error message.

Comment: Did you missed add Maybe type in `else (verEmails n xs)` ?

Comment: Why exactly are you converting this function to use `Maybe`?  It looks to me like you're more or less writing a customized `filter`, and lists return 0 or more values, while `Maybe` is for when you need to return 0 or 1 values.

Comment: @DavidUnric No, the error is `e : (verEmails n xs)` since `e :: String` and `verEmails n xs :: Maybe [String]`.

Comment: @DavidUnric you are right, but if i add `Just` after the else, it will double the error, exact same error doubles.

Comment: @bheklilr , i know, the function already does what i need, but the exercise, from college, asks to use Maybe :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem comes from trying to do `e : verEmails n xs`, since `verEmails n xs` does not return a list, but a list enclosed in `Maybe`.  The easiest way to handle this is to use the `Data.Maybe.fromMaybe` function:

```
fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a
fromMaybe onNothing Nothing = onNothing
fromMaybe onNothing (Just a) = a
```

Here I'm presuming you would want to return `Just aList` where `aList` contains all the emails filtered from the `Agenda` passed in.  This means that the only way `verEmails` will return `Nothing` is when the agenda passed in is empty.  So we have

```
verEmails n [] = Nothing
verEmails n ((nome, ((Email e):ls)):xs)
    = if n == nome
        then Just $ e : (fromMaybe [] $ verEmails n xs)
        else verEmails n xs
```

This just simply converts `verEmails n xs` from `Maybe [String]` to `[String]`, defaulting to the empty list, prepends `e`, then wraps it back up in a `Just`.

As a side note, your function does not cover all possible cases, what happens if I were to run `verEmails n ((nome, []):xs)`?  Or even `verEmails n ((nome, [Casa 1]):xs)`?

Comment: Thank you for the final tip, i was not doing the exercise with much caution. You are right, i should always pay attention to all possible cases. Thank you very much for your help bheklilr!